# How to vertically align UIButton text with UILabel text?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel

I have a table view cell and I have a label and button vertically aligned in vertical stack view. I want the text on UIButton to start right below UILabel. But even if I set the contentHorizontalAlignment on button to left, it still doesn't start from right below the label. I want 'S' of 'Select' right below 'L' of 'Label'. How do I achieve it?

***Code:***

```
self.selectPersonButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default buttons has `content insets`, you must change them to `custom`, to be able to set you own if you need.

[image]

in the picture shown the place of that configuration, change it to `custom` and set all insets to 0 , like in picture below.

[image]

Everything will work as you expect.

As an information starting from `iOS 15`  Apple added new way of configuring buttons, [apple document Button.Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration?changes=_4)